# I created a mail server using postfix and dovecot on ubuntu 20.04 but my mail goes to spam

Tags: email, postfix-mta, dovecot

I created a mail server using postfix and dovecot on ubuntu 20.04. I'm using a valid trusted SSL certificate from let's encrypt, but my mail goes to spam on Gmail and other mail services. I'm sending the email's with port 587 so what's my problem?

Comment: On top of your settings, even if they are perfect, there might be issue of your IP. Did you own this IP for long, do you have it on a server where it was yours, or did you got it from ISP where it changes from time to time. There is a chance somebody was using it for spam in the past, I had to manually request revokation from Microsoft  blocklist for example. And have a look at this: https://www.rackaid.com/blog/gmail-blacklist-removal/

Comment: does dovecot still work with gmail?  I'm thinking that they disabled that, somehow.  For example, I don't think that gmail works with the alpine mail client anymore.

Answer (score 1):

I recently configured my server using following manual:

- https://ubuntu.tutorials24x7.com/blog/install-mail-server-on-ubuntu-20-04-lts-using-postfix-dovecot-and-roundcube

There are few possible areas which can cause your emails in Junk folder (spam folder).
SPF, DKIM settings in your domain (DNS settings). If not configured properly, mail servers can suspect spoofing and warn their users.

You can send email to your Gmail mailbox and review "Show Original" to review **SPF, DKIM, DMARC**.

Additionally you can use:

- https://www.mail-tester.com/ - to get audit of problems: just simply send to a generated email address email from your server.